# Why the Twig don't provide ability to use PHP code?

Tags: php, twig

I don't fully understand why the Twig don't provide ability to use PHP code in twig templates? There is have some problem with security in this case? Why it to use such complex abstract layer?

Answer (score 3):

Twig is focused to designers not programmers.

If you want to use a PHP template just configure the template engine in your framework/application

Comment: Can I combine twig shortcut syntax like `{{ post.heading }}` with PHP buld-in functions, calling them directly like `<?php echo "Hello World" ?>`?

Comment: You must write a extension for that